# Cluster SSH on KDE fails: cssh error 'bad pad value "3m'

Tags: ssh, redhat, x11, x11forwarding, kde

I'm having issues getting clusterssh running on a RHEL7.3 install using KDE. I don't believe this is a Perl issue, as I have forwarded X from a CENTOS7 box that yields the same error (That box has no problem forwarding cssh from an Ubuntu/Gnome desktop).

Google only returns 2 results:
http://studiosysadmins.com/board/threadview/3755/

I have tried implementing one of the solutions suggested in the above thread:

```
user@host ~ $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-files.conf 
Section "Files"
    RgbPath "/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt"
EndSection
```

However it hasn't worked for me. I tend to live in Consoles and don't really do alot with KDE/Gnmoe and was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction. My environment is as follows:

```
user@host ~ $ cssh servers
bad pad value "3m": must be positive screen distance at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Tk/Widget.pm line 1218.
 at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Tk/Widget.pm line 203.

user@host ~ $ sudo rpm -qa | grep clusterssh
[sudo] password for michael.moser: 
clusterssh-4.02.03-2.el7.noarch

user@host ~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.3"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:client"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue on Fedora 25 running clusterssh version 4.08-1.fc25 via virtual machine using Virtualbox.

I tried various things such as messing with clusterssh configuration files and the user configuration files it generates and reinstalling the package, clustercssh, as well as downgrading it.However the error persisted.

I then decided to update to Virtualbox 5.1.16 r113841 (Qt5.6.2) from 5.1.14-112924 and reinstalled guest additions and rebooted both my virtual machine and physical machine (Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.14393). The issue is now gone after the restarts.

Comment: Sure, I updated to Virtualbox  5.1.16 r113841 (Qt5.6.2) from 5.1.14-112924. Running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro version 10.0.14393.

Comment: I'm not running virtual box, this is happening to my laptop

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/issues/108), with a fix ready to be released in the next `clusterssh` version